# Return response twice without polling or websockets

Tags: javascript, http, server, language-agnostic

Is there a way to make a server **send a response for a HTTP request twice**?

I need this showing on the client that the server has received the request(nut just that the client has sent. Some sort of an ACK.) and is processing it. And once it completes processing send the actual response.

I know that this is possible using long polling and websockets. But is there another way without multiple polling requests or maintaining connection?

Comment: No; that's impossible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events